Unable to log into Apple community with Account ID
I have an active account with the Apple community however, when I login it tells me I need to set up an account tell me that the screen that I want to use has been taken and I know it is because it’s my screen name

This can happen when Apple servers doing authorization have hiccups, outages or maintenance. Or when they push buggy code to their servers.

https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

I would try using that Apple ID on another service to test things, then consult the system status pages. (This should check your system for a wrong date, bad ssl trust chain, other things that need to be correct to log in)
I would try a new network if that’s easy (tether to a mobile, change to a coffee shop or another home) and then try incognito mode, resetting your browser cookies, data, cache, offline data, etc… In Safari, this is called private browsing.
If you can’t get logged in over an extended period (several hours and no issues logged) your last resort is opening a ticket with Apple. They can look at things server side, escalate to engineering, review their support path for this issue.
